# Cómo agregar cadenas a un arreglo en C

Tags: c, string

Quiero ingresar cadenas a un arreglo en C, el código que tengo es este:

```
int main()
{
    
    int sizeA;
    printf("Tamanio de arreglo\n");
    
    scanf("%i", &sizeA);
    
    char names[sizeA];
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++){
        printf("Nombre %c\n", i+1 );
        scanf("%c", &names[i]);
    }
    

    
    printf("valores arreglo\n");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++){
        printf("%c", names[i]);
    }



    return 0;
    
}
```

En primer lugar pregunto el tamaño del arreglo, en caso de ingresar `5` como longitud del arreglo, cuando ingreso el valor de las cadenas al momento de pedir el `Nombre` me sale dos veces la petición del nombre, lo que al final me deja ingresar solamente `2` veces la cadena y no las `5` que ingrese como longitud. Cómo puedo ingresar los 5 valores? Gracias de antemano. Cuando lo hago con enteros me deja ingresar correctamente los 5 valores y con cadenas no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varias cosas a tener en cuenta:

- En C, el tamaño de los arreglos debe ser constante. El compilador debería negarse a compilar.

  Para solucionar el primer problema, debes recurrir a la memoria dinámica si necesitas arreglos de longitud variable.

  Puedes reservar y liberar memoria con [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) y [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) respectivamente. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  int size = 0;
  scanf("%i", &size);
  // Reservas memoria
  // malloc recibe el número de bytes a reservar como parámetro 
  int* arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      scanf("%i", &arr[i]);
  }
  // Liberas la memoria al terminar de usarla
  free(arr);
  ```
- Es preferible usar `scanf` solo para leer números o valores booleanos. Para caracteres o strings (no es necesario leer o escribir caracteres individualmente), [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) y [`gets_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) son mejores opciones.
- Al leer números, `scanf` deja el salto de línea de manera similar a como ocurre en C++.

  En C puedes descartar el caracter con [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) (equivalente a `fgetc(stdin)`). En C++ lo puedes hacer con [`std::cin.ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).
- Un **string** es un arreglo de caracteres (`char*` o `char[]`). Si quieres un arreglo de strings, sería `char[][]`, `char*[]`, `char[]*` o `char**` (cuanto trabajes con memoria dinámica es más probable que uses el último).

  Algunos ejemplos:

  ```
  // Arreglo de nombres de 10 caracteres (9 sin el caracter nulo)
  char nombres[][10] = { "Juan", "Pablo", "Tobías" };

  // Arreglo de 5 nombres de 10 caracteres (9 sin el caracter nulo)
  char nombres[5][10] = { "Juan", "Pablo", "Tobías" };

  // Arreglo de nombres (como punteros) sin límite de tamaño
  char *nombres[] = { "Juan", "Pablo", "Tobías" };
  ```

---

Con todas las correcciones, obtendrías un código como este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRING_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int sizeA;
    printf("Tamaño de arreglo:\n");
    
    scanf("%i", &sizeA);
    // Quita el salto de línea que scanf deja en stdin al leer números.
    getchar();
    
    // Reservas memoria para cada puntero
    char** names = malloc(sizeA * sizeof(char*));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++){
        // Reservas memoria para cada nombre
        names[i] = malloc(STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
        printf("Nombre %i:\n", i+1);
        gets_s(names[i], STRING_SIZE);
    }
    
    printf("\nNombres:\n");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++){
        printf("%i: %s\n", i + 1, names[i]);
    }

    return 0;
    
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##jZK/btswEMZ3PsXBgRvZVpw4QJcmLuAhKNLBQGtPjYOCpk42C@qYklKBNvDDZOyQociWVQ/mnCj/UYyiqAaJOh5//O67UycLpdbrI03KFAnCpc8TbfvL9@JVyOj5YcxpWlQxcZRgqglhMv18Pf7wdXL95QoGZ0JoyiGTmqKOuBfATxXw@heOLsLvHRPyNGpNZSbLPxYYK53DhbHvZtTq1Enh5ZUkTmzrVgxvAmGze3oKnwqdS0ADXpo8QEz5SCjhe4H1QY594wyCqjQCacAgOqDyOUNnfX@nTS0dDGGBuVpKF22u0ClEYWMIxzM67oRgU/6MJsh0ZSl35RMUdKikP6N9Pax4bIFQoWfdHhaFdIl0VQFKOqlyVsZSC5LwQzot5waBNBhOLZ9NrjNenG/AG@mMvPLgrbFwxwjILDeHkZUBjMIUVW5jWMqffxO3d7mqutsFkhl69iGTxlgVBbuhGxpn0ygkdZrNSa2LKvc0nzm74M/lpsmge73O/c6vwL3Rt3t0c2BeXbDlN20e22zuENq6Go6Y2YNGUspN89H2hrg5inHd9kbybvGv6TFYPiZsqHU1fHeoKtWwrUPmOl7sbm3csA3dVIknMLgN1oTt1d64/QDVtfnDsf9fZ7cg9gbavrYHejCI4UDbSoSPw7xwtFUkVuv1WzEyksSIElf@9mKis/KJxMeCY1OblQ9evAA).